# Limiting the number of relationships to a record with MySQL or Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, relationship

I am looking for a way to limit the number of items that a Laravel model can have.

Model A can have up to 5 model B's related to it, but no more than 5. So far I have a many to many relationship between A and B but that allows for an unlimited amount of relationships between the two.

Something like this

```
A1 | B1
A1 | B2
A1 | B3
A1 | B4
A1 | B5
```

Trying to add `A1 | B6` would either return an error from MySQL on insert or from Laravel before attempting the insert.

I was looking for something like MySQL's unique that could be applied to the A column but limiting to 5 instead of 1 occurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is a builtin way to do this in laravel. and if I understand your question correctly, what you can look into is laravel model events

> Eloquent models fire several events, allowing you to hook into the following points in a model's lifecycle: retrieved, creating, created, updating, updated, saving, saved,  deleting, deleted, restoring, restored. Events allow you to easily execute code each time a specific model class is saved or updated in the database.

So you can hook into one of the events like `creating`,`saving` then check if the database has appropriate number of relations and stop the db operation by throwing some exception

**The pseudo code here might help**

```
class A1{
   protected $dispatchesEvents = [
      'saving' => A1SavingEvent::class,

   ];
   .....
   .....
}

//The handle method of the Listener for the A1SavingEvent

public function handle(){
   if(count(A1->B1) > 5){
      throw CountExceededException('You already have 5 relations')
   }
}
```

[Doc Link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#events)